# sass keys and values mapping from one sass file to the other

Tags: sass, node-modules

I have multiple scss files.

Example:

main.scss:  The main file contains a list of colors, here I’ve used only 2 as an example.

```
$ex-color-main: (

    ‘red’: (
        ‘bg’      : #bd1118,
        ‘text’    : #fff,
    ),

    ‘green’: (
        ‘bg’      : #93b923,
        ‘text’    : #fff,
    ),

);

$ex-print-bg: true !default;
$ex-print-color: true !default;
$color: $ex-color-main;

@if ($ex-color-classes == true) {
    @each $key, $value in $color {
        @include ex-create-classes($key, $value, $ex-print-bg, $ex-print-color);
    }
}

@if ($ex-colors-cssvars == true) {

    :root {
        @each $key, $value in $color {
            --ex-color--#{$key}: #{map-get($value, ‘bg’)};
            --ex-fgcolor--#{$key}: #{map-get($value, ‘text’)};
        }
    }
}
```

I’m using npm node modules to compile. The main file compiles to css files as below:

ex-color-classes.css:

```
.ex-color--red {
    color: #bd1118; }

.ex-color—-green {
    color: #93b923; }
```

ex-color-css-vars.css:

```
:root {
    —-ex-bg-—red: #bd1118;
    —-ex-color-—red: #fff;
    —-ex-bg—-green: #93b923;
    —-ex-color—-green: #fff; }
```

page.scss: The page file must include the color from main and again, it is a very long list

```
$ex-color-page: (

    ‘danger’: include keys and values from red,

    ‘success’: include keys and values from green,

);
```

I can use:

```
$ex-color-page: (

    ‘danger’: (
        ‘bg’: var(--ex-bg--red),
        ‘text’: var(--ex-color--red),
    ),

    ‘success’: (
        ‘bg’: var(--ex-bg--green),
        ‘text’: var(--ex-color--green),
    ),

);
```

But I would like to know, is there a cleaner and better way to import the keys and values from the main.scss to page.scss?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a cleaner way to do it:

```
$ex-color-page: (

    ‘danger’: map-get($ex-color-main, 'red'),

    ‘success’: map-get($ex-color-main, 'green'),

);
```